# Qt invoke method directly to the QThread eventloop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals, qmetaobject

In my application I'm using a non-Qt class that spawns its own thread. This object listens on a device and calls a callback each time the device received a packet.

In my Device class (derrived from QObject), I have a static function, that receives the callback and should then call a member function of the actual object.

```cpp
//super sample code
Device::Device(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void Device::startCapture(pcpp::PcapLiveDevice *dev)
{
    // open the device before start capturing/sending packets
    if (!dev->open())
    {
        return;
    }

    dev->startCapture(callback, this);

}

//this is a static function
void Device::callback(pcpp::RawPacket *packet, pcpp::PcapLiveDevice *dev, void *cookie)
{
    pcpp::Packet* parsed = new Packet(packet,true);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(static_cast<Device*>(cookie), "processPacket", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(pcpp::Packet*, parsed));        
}

void Device::processPacket(pcpp::Packet *packet)
{
    //do something in its living QThread
}
```

The Device object has its own QThread, as I'm doing heavy analysis in the background. The main thread should not get involved if possible. The problem is that the wiki states (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

"If type is Qt::QueuedConnection, a QEvent will be sent and the member is invoked as soon as the application enters the main event loop."

This sounds like the main thread needs to handle every single packet at least to forward it to the thread where the Device object is living.

Isn't there an option to call the function in the QThread where the current object lives in without using the main thread at all?

(The QThread surely has its own EventLoop)

Comment: Do you use `moveToThread` ? Can you should your `connect` ?

Comment: Yes, every Device instance in moved to a QThread object with moveToThread. But all instances share this one static callback. So I'm using the cookie in the callback to call the actual member function. As the callback does not happen in the target thread I use "invokeMethod" to execute the target function in the correct thread.

Comment: may be try Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as it also does it the same way as QueuedConnection. Also I don't want to freeze the callback thread, as the pcap device uses this thread to process the packets

Comment: I'm looking for a threadsafe way to insert the QEvent directly into the cooresponding QThread without using to main thread.

Comment: You need to show more code, including `connect` and `moveToThread` calls.

Comment: I can only give more sample code, as this is way to much to post it here. To sum it up, I have several signal and slots which are used to communicate with the UI thread, and some other object that do not live in the ui thread. I mostly use Autoconnection or QueuedConenctions for the connection.

Just adding to this: the above strategy is working. I just don't like the idea of passing every single packet packet in a QEvent to the main event loop just to forward it to the specific thread. I would prefer a solution, where I could directly queue it in the correct thread instead.